# SQL Server 2008R2 query stalling

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables, TableA and TableB

TableA contains nearly 3,000,000 records
TableB contains about 10,000 records

I want to delete the entries in TableA that match a certain parameters. This query has qorked OK for smaller tables, but I get timeout exceptions when running in VB.Net

```
delete FROM TableA WHERE (((TableA.ID) In (SELECT [TableB].ID FROM TableB)) AND ((TableA.EVDATE)='20170720'));
```

In an effort to see what's going on, I changed this to a SELECT * FROM... in SSMS and at 5 minutes with no result, I stopped it...

Why does this stall and is there a better way of doing this?

I think this is much better to read:

```
delete FROM TableA  WHERE TableA.EVDATE='20170720' and  TableA.ID In 
(SELECT [TableB].ID FROM TableB);
```

Comment: Use parenthesis only when **needed**. Unnecessary parenthesis will make the code clumsy and difficult to understand

Comment: Creating a Index on `TableA.ID` and `TableA.EVDATE` will help the query to run faster..

Comment: Also joining instead of using `IN` might be faster, you would need to try.

Comment: I created a nonclustered index and that seems to have vastly improved the performance. `Create NonClustered Index IX_IndexName On TableA
(ID Asc, EVDATE Asc);`

Comment: @Tym I updated your query above to read much better to the viewer.

Comment: Thanks @reds - that looks a bit better

Comment: I suggest when deleting a record from your database you must do a backup first.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the number of deleted records into multiple calls

Example:

Delete Each 1000 Rows Alone

```
DELETE FROM TableA 
WHERE TableA.ID IN (SELECT TOP (1000) ID FROM TableA)
```

and you can make a loop over them and Check @@ROWS_COUNT if 0 then all rows were deleted and no need to recall or IF @@ROWS_COUNT < 1000 then no need to recall

The big query needs a lot of transaction log resources (DatabaseName_Log.mdb File not the database file) and when you split you will benefit from lower resources and lower logs which allows faster executions per smaller number of records to delete

Comment: This doesn't take into account the need for `AND TableA.EVDATE='20170720'`. I tried your suggestion but at 00:02:00 it was still running.

Comment: This is wrong.. Every time the sub-query can return the same 1000 records which is already deleted!!

Comment: I think it is much better to create a stored proc to increment that top(1000). Or to delete data specifically.

Comment: The client has to do all the work so there's no stored procedures.

Comment: i said "make a loop over them", he can loop over C# which is better 
since stored procedure will still the same issue, storedprocedure faster but in this case we will have the same DataBase_Log issue since will use storedprocedure as full delete query